# Eclipse Plugin: Show context function on all class-Files in external JARs

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am developing an Eclipse plugin and I want to add an entry in the context menu in the Project Explorer. The entry should only be visible when a class-File is selected.

Adding the following to my plugin.xml File works. However, it does not work when I select a class-File in an External JAR. What is the reason for this behavior and how can I achieve that my context menu is visible in this case too?

```
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.ui.popup.any">
         <command
               commandId="my_command"
               label="Test"
               style="push">
               <visibleWhen>                           
                    <iterate
                         ifEmpty="false">
                     <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
                       <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value="*class" />
                     </adapt>
                    </iterate>
                </visibleWhen>
         </command>
      </menuContribution>
```

[image: Context menu entry "Test" is shown]
[image: Context menu entry "Test" is NOT shown]

Comment: Objects in a jar are not files and certainly aren't IFiles - only files in the workspace are IFiles.

Comment: Good to know. How are objects in a jar represented in Eclipse? By which interface?

Comment: Possibly `IJavaElement` but I am not sure.

Comment: According to the _Plug-in Selection Spy_ (Alt+Shift+F1) it's an `IOrdinaryClassFile` (which is a specific `IJavaElement`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to user greg-449 and howlger I solved my problem. The problem was that an object in a JAR file is not represented as an IFile. Therefore, I adapted the visibleWhen section:

```
<visibleWhen>                          
    <iterate ifEmpty="false">
          <instanceof value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.IOrdinaryClassFile" />
    </ iterate>
</visibleWhen>
```